# decimal values in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, decimal

How to display a decimal value in the gridview. Say if user enters a value 0.5, it got inserted into DB as 0.5, but while diplaying it back on the the front end , it is displayed as 0.50.

How to avoid this scenario.

And also the user should be able to enter 5 places after the decimal point.
Like 0.12345 is acceptable
and 0.123456 is not acceptable.

How to restrict this..

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Apply client-side javascript for formatting the value to the desired scale and precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can do string formatting inside an `Eval` statement using `String.Format`-style rules when you're databinding:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decimal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("DecimalValue", "{0:0.#####}") %>' runat="server"  />&nbsp;
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This label will have up to five digits after the decimal point, so you'll see 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 etc but *not* 0.1000. See [Custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

For data entry, I'd probably use the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) to put a mask on a TextBox:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decimal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("DecimalValue", "{0:0.#####}") %>' runat="server"  />&nbsp;
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# Bind("DecimalValue", "0.#####") %>' />&nbsp;
        <ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" MaskType="Number" Mask="99999.99999" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The masked edit extender attached to the textbox will only accept numbers (`MaskType="Number"`), fills in empty mask characters with zeroes (also from the mask type) and will accept up to six digits either side of the decimal point (`Mask="999999.99999`).

Comment: Text='<% #Eval("Threshold_Min","{0:0.#####}") %>'

Could you please explain me in details actually the text box should accept the values between 0 and 999999.
The Values may be between 0.00000 to 999999.99999.

Please help